# Как отправить файл через CallbackQuery

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'tests')
async def send_file(message: types.Document):
   await message.answer_document(open("E:\\BOT\\_info\\навички.docx", 'rb'))
```

AttributeError: 'CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'answer_document'

Подскажите как правильно написать код

Answer (score 0):

В Callback-обработчиках первым аргументом **всегда** должен стоять объект `CallbackQuery`, что у Вас там `types.Document` делает? Из объекта `CallbackQuery` Вы можете вытащить `Message` и ответить на него:

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'tests')
async def send_file(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    with open("E:\\BOT\\_info\\навички.docx", 'rb') as file
        await query.message.answer_document(file)
```